# When I try to connect to a localhost it starts printing out crazy outputs that I can't understand

Tags: reactjs, npm, localhost

[This is the output that I see when I type in http-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSqfB.jpg)

I updated my node version and then I created a react app through terminal. I then ran the http-server command to show the localhost site as I usually do but then I keep getting this output. I'm not sure what the issue is and the localhost site just fails to load while this output keeps printing out in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I think your local server might be haunted. Try contacting a priest or set up another working environment from scratch.